# Convert datetime column with multiple timezones to epoch timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime column with **multiple** timezones that I want to convert to epoch timestamp:

```python
pd.DataFrame(['2020-09-29 09:30:00-04:00', '2020-09-29 10:30:00-04:00', '2020-09-29 11:00:00-05:00'], columns = ['datetime'])
```

The desired results look like:

```
                    datetime   timestamp
0  2020-09-29 09:30:00-04:00  1601386200
1  2020-09-29 10:30:00-04:00  1601389800
2  2020-09-29 11:00:00-05:00  1601395200
```

(note `2020-09-29 11:00:00` has a `-05:00` tz)

I tried:

```python
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).astype(int) // 10 ** 9
```

It works well when `datetime` has only one timezone info but throws a `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'` error when the timezone info is different and I'm not sure why Pandas cannot recognize this.

I assume people may ask similar questions but couldn't find the exact solution. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed time zone, so you want to pass `utc=True` to `to_datetime`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], utc=True).astype(int) // 10 ** 9
```

Output:

```
0    1601386200
1    1601389800
2    1601395200
Name: datetime, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.Timestamp`:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: int(pd.Timestamp(x).timestamp()))
df

datetime    timestamp
0   2020-09-29 09:30:00-04:00   1601386200
1   2020-09-29 10:30:00-04:00   1601389800
2   2020-09-29 11:00:00-05:00   1601395200
```